# Is DataSet or DataTable value type in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, reference, dataset

I know `DataSet` and `DataTable` are **classes** thus they must be **reference** **types**.

But whenever I pass them in any method, I have to `return ds` or `dt` to get them filled.

Example:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
FillDataSet(ds); //This get data from database
```

This will not fill my dataset but below one will.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds = FillDataSet(ds); //This get data from database
```

I am unable to understand, if I am sending an `object` of `DataSet` `class` then it should be filled by reference.

Let say `FillDataSet(ds)` gets data from database.

Comment: Without seeing the implementation of ```FillDataSet()``` it's difficult to reach a conclusion. From what you've described it sounds like ```FillDataSet()``` is copying the data from one to another, instead of actually filling it.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases you are doing Call By Value in the function- `FillDataSet`.

The `FillDataSet` function here seems to copy the data to a new DataSet and return it. So a new object get's created. If you want to make the former code work, you might have to pass the parameter as a reference into the FillDataSet() function. Some thing like this- `FillDataSet(ref ds)`.

Also refer this- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx

Answer (score 1):

First thing you have to remember is reference type variables and pass by reference are two entirely different concepts. Here you are passing the value of the object(ds) even though they are of reference type variables.

In both cases that you mentioned above you are actually passing the values of the dataset, in the second case you are assigning the return value of the function to the variable, you have to take a look at here

Comment: Hi, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx , The following keywords are used to declare reference types:
class
,interface
,delegate ,dynamic
,object
,string

Comment: Their is no doubt and confusions, `DataSet` is a reference type variable, but here you are passing its value not the reference

Answer (score 0):

A little modification of your example

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            FillDataSet(ds);
        }

       private static void FillDataSet(DataSet ds)
       {
        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();//Say you have created an new instance of Class DataSet.

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        ds2.Tables.Add(dt);
        ds = ds2; //here ds is now referencing address of ds2 created by new DataSet()
       }
    }
```

Now since your `ds` is not the `ds` you sent into the `FillDataSet(ds)` method,

this situation is equivalent to if you would have done `ds = new DataSet();` inside `FillDataSet(ds);`

Hope this explains the situation. Do comment if you have any doubts.